# Sending and Receiving byte[] array using timer in Java

Tags: java, sockets, timer

I am trying to send a byte[] array using socket but using a timer.
I want to send byte[] for every 1000milliseconds. Along with the timer i have one button where byte[] has to be sent on click on the button.

When i run my code if i click the button data is not being sent if i use Timer in my code and only send sent from timer is being sent but not received.If timer is not used then button click works.

My code for sending is

```
channel1=new JLabel("Channel 1");
channel1.setBounds(80, 140, 80, 30);
channel1.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15));
contentPane.add(channel1);

channel1Field=new JTextField();
channel1Field.setBounds(55, 200, 120, 30);
channel1Field.setEnabled(true);     
contentPane.add(channel1Field);

channel1send=new JButton("Send 1");
channel1send.setBounds(65, 270, 100, 30);
channel1send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(!(channel1Field.getText().equals("")))
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(channel1send.isEnabled())
            {

               new Thread(new Channel1()).start();                                        

            }             
            }
            else
            {
                 JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Field cannot be 
                                         empty", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("FAILURE");
                 dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                 dialog.setVisible(true);
            }

        }
    });
    contentPane.add(channel1send);

        new Thread(new timer()).start();

    }
    class timer implements Runnable     
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Timer timer = new Timer();
             timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 4000);


        }

    }
class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
  //     System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
        try
        {   
        byte[] com=new byte[]{0x01,(byte)0xFE};
        socket=new Socket("192.168.1.115",8002);
        DataOutputStream dw=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        dw.writeInt(com.length);
        dw.write(com);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(com));
        for(byte b:com)
          {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));

          }
          sentmessage.append("Timer Sent -  " + sb.toString() + "\n");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
           {
               if(socket==null)
               {
                   try {
                //  socket.close();
                    socket=new Socket("192.168.1.115",8002);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                }
               }
           }

    }
  }


class Channel1 implements Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String message1=channel1Field.getText();
            int msg1=Integer.parseInt(message1);
command=new byte[]{(byte)0xFE,0x01,0x02,(byte)msg1,0x00,0x00,(byte)0xFD};
        DataOutputStream dw=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dw.writeInt(command.length);
            dw.write(command);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
            for(byte b:command)
              {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));

              }
sentmessage.append("Client Sent to Channel 2 -  " + sb.toString() + "\n");


        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            sentmessage.append("channel 2 on failed");
        }
          finally
           {
               if(socket==null)
               {
                   try {
                //  socket.close();
                    socket=new Socket("192.168.1.115",8002);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                }
               }
           }                                
    }

}
```

my Receiving code is

```
DataInputStream dw= new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    while(true)
    {
      int len = dw.readInt();
      System.out.println(len);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
      System.out.println(bytes);
      dw.readFully(bytes);
      System.out.println("Client sent: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
      StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
      for(byte b:bytes)
      {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));

      }
      text1.append("Server Received : " + sb.toString() + "\n");
    } 
  }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("connection failed");
        con.setText("CONNECTION FAILED");
    }
}
```

I want to receive data sent from the timer and button click .how would i achieve this.Kindly help.I did'nt get the solution for this in the internet.

Comment: Where are you sending the message every 1000 ms in the code I can't find `1000` anywhere.

Comment: I am not able to find what is wrong in my code

Comment: You are only sending the message once. Do you want it to be at a fixed rate?

Comment: ya i want timer to send message continously and receiving side should receive properly.